# htaccess rewrite rule overpowers deny ip

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to deny access to my WordPress site while it's under construction. I have denied all other IP which appears to work fine when I comment out WP part of htaccess. When WP part of htacess is present and I access from forbiden IP, index.php page gets displayed, just without css or images.
Can someone explain how it happens and how to prevent it?
Thanks!

```
# ALLOW USER BY IP
<Limit GET POST>
 Require all denied
 Require ip 93.112.174.
</Limit>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: Not exactly sure why this is happening. The only two things I can suggest are to either move the `<Limit/>` block to your server configuration file, if accessible, or to only allow your IP using `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ...`.

Answer (score 0):

One answer from user got deleted so I can't mark it as solution... Thanks! :)
Using rewrite rules was most simple way to achieve what I wanted, works fine on latest stable Apache 2.4.18

```
<If "-R '93.112.0.0/16'">
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
    # END WordPress
</If>
<Else>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^ - [F]
</Else>
```